# Call a function from another component using composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Below is a code for a header and a body (different components). How do you call the continue function of the component 2 and pass a parameter when you are inside component 1, using composition API way...

Component 2:

```js
export default {
    setup() {
        const continue = (parameter1) => {
            // do stuff here
        }
        
        return {
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `this.$parent` in the component to access it's parents instance

Comment: @power-cut You can but you shouldn't. It was a bad practice in AngularJS, where $parent came from to Vue

Comment: @EstusFlask I completely agree. But nothing exists without a reason. There are many ways to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use events for parent-to-child communication, combined with template refs, from which the child method can be directly called.

1. In `ComponentB.vue`, emit an event (e.g., named `continue-event`) that the parent can listen to. We use a button-click  to trigger the event for this example:

```html
<!-- ComponentB.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  emits: ['continue-event'],
}
</script>

<template>
  <h2>Component B</h2>
  <button @click="$emit('continue-event', 'hi')">Trigger continue event</button>
</template>
```

2. In the parent, use a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs) on `ComponentA.vue` to get a reference to it in JavaScript, and create a function (e.g., named `myCompContinue`) to call the child component's `continueFn` directly.

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  ⋮
  setup() {
    const myComp = ref()
    const myCompContinue = () => myComp.value.continueFn('hello from B')

    return {
      myComp,
      myCompContinue,
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <ComponentA ref="myComp" />
  ⋮
</template>
```

3. To link the two components in the parent, use the [`v-on` directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on) (or `@` shorthand) to set `myCompContinue` as the event handler for `ComponentB.vue'`s `continue-event`, emitted in step 1:

```html
<template>
  ⋮
  <ComponentB @continue-event="myCompContinue" />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-invoke-sibling-component-method?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FComponentB.vue)

**Note:** Components written with the Options API (as you are using in the question) by default have their methods and props exposed via template refs, but this is not true for components written with `<script setup>`. In that case, [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) would be needed to expose the desired methods.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I solved it with script setup syntax:

Parent:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const childComponent = ref(null);

const onSave = () => {
    childComponent.value.saveThing();
};
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent ref="childComponent" />

        <SomeOtherComponent
            @save-thing="onSave"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

ChildComponent:

```
<script setup>
const saveThing = () => {
    // do stuff
};

defineExpose({
    saveThing,
});
</script>
```

It doesn't work without `defineExpose`. Besides that, the only trick is to create a ref on the component in which you are trying to call a function.

In the above code, it doesn't work to do `@save-thing="childComponent.saveThing"`, and it appears the reason is that the ref is null when the component initially mounts.